# Service to Directly Push or Business Logic to Handle

Tags: c#, service

**Update:**

Essentially rather then have Server A's Service write directly to the database, or data table.  Have the Service assign values to a series of `Properties` within the Business Logic.  So that all the calculations and data access will be done directly on Server B.

Something that may not have been clear, Server A is the client that is consuming the Service.

---

So I have a unique quandary, that is what would be the standard way to handle this particular issue. I'm currently faced with an option to use a *Service* or *Inner Logic*.  The scenario:

- Two Servers
- Server A: Pushes request to Server B.
- Server B: Takes these request and variables and implements the Business Logic.
- Server B: Is going to be creating relational data access anyways so its doubling workload.

The dilemma is I'm unsure of the *standard* or *best* way to handle this.  What I mean, is it better to have *Server A Datamap* directly to the Database?  Or is it more viable to have *Server A Store to Properties* then let the inner logic handle it?

The reason I'm asking is obviously solution one will result in rapid development, but will encounter issues in the future or just poor performance.

Such as:

- Server B: Will persistently be filling *Data Tables*
- Server B: All of the persistence at this point will be from it's own retrieval of data from the database.
- Will make it hard to refactor possibly as the project grows.

Those are my initial concerns, so I was leaning towards option two.  But as I stated I'm not sure if my mindset is following the norm or standard.

To avoid this being considered a debate;

> **Do the short comings of option one, tend to impact the fluidity of any project as complexity grows? Will the implementation of option two be more feasible, as I can implement a better commonality of access directly to the Data Access Layer?**

Thank you for that help, hopefully I clear expressed myself accordingly to where this makes sense.  If not please throw a comment so I may edit accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "Server A Store to Properties then let the inner logic handle it"? I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, but you could use a services oriented approach instead of relying in the database for communication across boundaries. One option is to use webservices such as WCF or Web Api or you could also add a queue such as MSMQ in order to pass messages across applications.

Comment: @tucaz I added some specification.

Answer (score 0):

To a certain degree "it depends".  From a particular functional standpoint, whatever works is correct.

You many have many non-functional or design requirements that come into play that might restrict or guide a particular implementation.  For example, if your design is supposed to be Service Oriented (SOA) then each server is supposed to be autonomous.  This means they *shouldn't* share a database (they shouldn't even share a schema).  In cases like this message-orientation is generally a good pattern to go with.  You might want to look things like the consumer/producer pattern and message-oriented middle-ware like queues or service buses.  In which case Server A would push a message (Command) to Server B which would process it.  You might use Request/Reply pattern to get a "reply" back to Server A.  Or, Server B might simply send another message (Event) back to A to tell it it's done the work.

## update:

The "data" that Server B uses would entirely be sent to it from B in the message.

Comment: Unfortunately Server A has a database that relates to the ECommerce for a bulk of projects and intranet.  Where Server B is a stand alone product that is structured strictly for the users and there accounts.  Unfortunately someone thought the best approach was to integrate this registration directly into the ECommerce Application.  So I'm forced into this mess now. I appreciate the answer, I might be able to make that work I'll have to look into it.